# How to store Date types in database via persistence?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have a Entity class with Date type variable. When I persist that object I got an java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setDob([Ljava.lang.String;) error.

My Field

```
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dob;
```

I set the value for it as..

```
customer.setDob(super.getDob());
```

super.getDob() returns dob(a Date).
setDob parameter type is Date

How can I fix this.

Comment: Give us more info -> what's the return type of super.getDob(), what type customer.setDob(?) accepts, etc

Comment: returns Date(mentioned as My Field). and parameter type is Date.

Comment: The error message shows that the code tries to call setDob by passing an array of Strings, and not a Date. Without the full stack trace and the relevant code, it's hard to help more.